# State the rule!

Tags: pattern, knowledge, letter-sequence

State the rule behind the following partition of letters, and fill 
in the questionmarks. (The puzzle has a clear and justifiable trivia-type solution.)

```
      A . . D E . G H I . K . . N O . . . S T . . . ? ? ?
   ---------------------------------------------------------
      . B C . . F . . . J . L M . . P Q R . . U V W ? ? ?
```

Comment: Is the fact that the **I** is written with three strokes significant for the solution?

Comment: No, the shape of the letters is not significant for the solution.

Comment: Capital versus lowercase is not significant. It is a trivia-type puzzle.

Comment: I was going to guess that they are divided in half according to the most and least used letters in English language, but I checked and it doesn't match.

Comment: I've been trying to tie it to US states abbreviations, counts, capitals.. something - considering the title is "state the rule"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The rule appears to be:

> The last letters of the names of U.S. states.
>
>  **A**
>  Alabam**a**
>  Alask**a**
>  Arizon**a**
>  Californi**a**
>  Florid**a**
>  Georgi**a**
>  Indian**a**
>  Iow**a**
>  Louisian**a**
>  Minnesot**a**
>  Montan**a**
>  Nebrask**a**
>  Nevad**a**
>  North Carolin**a**
>  North Dakot**a**
>  Oklahom**a**
>  Pennsylvani**a**
>  South Carolin**a**
>  South Dakot**a**
>  Virgini**a**
>  West Virgini**a**
>
>  **D**
>  Marylan**d**
>  Rhode Islan**d**
>
>  **E**
>  Delawar**e**
>  Main**e**
>  New Hampshir**e**
>  Tennesse**e**
>
>  **G**
>  Wyomin**g**
>
>  **H**
>  Uta**h**
>
>  **I**
>  Hawai**i**
>  Mississipp**i**
>  Missour**i**
>
>  **K**
>  New Yor**k**
>
>  **N**
>  Michiga**n**
>  Orego**n**
>  Washingto**n**
>  Wisconsi**n**
>
>  **O**
>  Colora**o**
>  Idah**o**
>  New Mexic**o**
>  Ohi**o**
>
>  **S**
>  Arkansa**s**
>  Illinoi**s**
>  Kansa**s**
>  Massachusett**s**
>  Texa**s**
>
>  **T**
>  Connecticu**t**
>  Vermon**t**

So of the last three letters,

> **Y** (Kentuck**y**, New Jerse**y**) is on the top row, X and Z on the bottom.