# Again: State the rule!

Tags: pattern, knowledge, letter-sequence

This puzzle continues the puzzle
"[State the rule!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/state-the-rule)".

State the rule behind the following partition of letters, and fill 
in the questionmarks. (The puzzle has a clear and justifiable trivia-type solution.)

```
      A . C . E . G H . J . . M . . . . R S . . V W ? ? ? 
   ---------------------------------------------------------
      . B . D . F . . I . K L . N O P Q . . T U . . ? ? ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Letters above the line have been initals for the names of legitimate Kings or Queens of England, while those below the line haven't.

So XYZ go all below the line by the way.

Comment: I can't find anyone with "V" as an initial, at least not on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_monarchs#Timeline_of_English_monarchs)

Comment: @Engineer Toast That list goes to 1707. Since then, the title of king/queen of England is included in the wider title of king/queen of Great Britain. This is the list since 1707 until nowadays  including queen Victoria [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_monarchs)

Comment: Yep, my error. Thanks. This would fit with the title, too, if it's "Head of State"